# How to fix PHP ftp_mlsd returning false

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to get all files from an FTP server using `MLSD`, but the `ftp_mlsd()` function keeps returning `false`.

The server I am connecting with is a test server: speedtest.tele2.net.
The connection does work when using `ftp_nlist()`.

My code currently:

```
$host = "speedtest.tele2.net";
$ftpConnection = ftp_connect($host);
$login = ftp_login($ftpConnection,'anonymous','password');

$directory = ftp_mlsd($ftpConnection,'.');

var_dump($directory);

ftp_close($ftpConnection);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FTP server does not support `MLSD` command.

```
C:\>ftp speedtest.tele2.net
Connected to speedtest.tele2.net.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
User (speedtest.tele2.net:(none)): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> quote FEAT    
211-Features:         # It's not announced in features list
 EPRT
 EPSV
 MDTM
 PASV
 REST STREAM
 SIZE
 TVFS
211 End
ftp> quote MLSD    
500 Unknown command.  # And the response is also pretty clear
ftp>
```